# Reading a file to a dictionary and trying to rank

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a file that looks as follows:

```
(u'castro', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'catcher', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'center', 4.3730265046954591)
(u'caus', 5.0661736852554045)
```

How can I read this file to a python dictionary and then sort it as per the scores?

```
d={}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val= line.strip().split()
        d[key]=val
```

I am trying to sort by val in this case, and then get the result in the following form:

```
(u'castro', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'catcher', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'caus', 5.0661736852554045)
(u'center', 4.3730265046954591)
```

Comment: Your code isn't indented correctly, please fix it. Note that a Python dictionary is an _unordered_ collection, so there's not much point in trying to sort one. There _is_ an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) subclass of `dict` in the `collections` module , but I suspect that a simple `list` is all you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces a nested list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

with open("scores.txt") as f:
    lst = [i.rstrip("\n")[1:-1].split(", ") for i in f.readlines()]


for i in lst:
    i[1] = float(i[1])
    i[0] = i[0][2:-1]

lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[['castro', 5.471638793363569], ['catcher', 5.471638793363569], ['caus', 5.0661736852554045], ['center', 4.373026504695459]]
```

To write the names to a file:

```
with open("scores2.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in lst:
        f.write("{}\n".format(i[0]))
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the output in the same format as the input? The reason being I need it in that format for further processing.

Comment: That's probably the closest you're going to get to the input format.

Comment: Hey, this doesn't seem to sort the list: This is the output I get:
[['trial', 5.471638793363569], ['faint', 4.555348061489413], ['nevertheless', 5.471638793363569]

Comment: I think you meant (key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

Comment: Hi, one more thing. What if I only want to print the text values to the file but in order. Like castro, catcher, caus?

Comment: Yes. It did! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries do not have order,all you can do is to create a sorted representation.

```
import operator
d={}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
     key, val= line.strip().split()
     d[key]=val

sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print sorted_d
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes,that is true should be .itemgetter(0).

Comment: I wish to keep the results in the format shown above. I am receiving the output in this format: ("(u'castro',", '5.4716387933635691)') 
How do I get rid of the extra double quotes and brackets?